# Turn off autocomplete suggestion bar with InputScope="Text"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, textbox

There is a normal WP7 suggestion bar when I set up this `<TextBox InputScope="Text" />` property. Is there a way to remove the bar? I need InputScope="Text" for auto-capitalizing first letter and other [typing features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426929%28VS.95%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatley not. There is no way to fine grain the InputScope behaviour beyond what comes by default.

The inputscope definitions include whether the auto-complete options are use or not. If you really don't want autocomplete then you'll need to select from the ones which don't include it.